# Convert a column of 1s into a timetable

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking into the possibility of converting a column of 1s with headers into a timetable. I have attached a snippet of what the problem will look like. I have a row of 1s showing where a potential employee is working and a blank cell showing where they are not. so the very first 1 is the employees start time. the first blank cell after the first one is morning tea. the first 1 after the morning tea blank is back to work so on and so forth.

I would like to create a set of formulas that is able to read the data and convert it into a timetable also attached.

For example the first row of ones would be start time 7.30, Morning tea 8.30, lunch 10.30, afternoon tea 13.45 finish 16.00.

Employees will always have a morning tea, lunch and afternoon tea however their start time and finish time may be at different times to the ones shown in screenshot

[The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgrQr.png)

[image]

[The ideal solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykXyj.png)

[image]

Comment: Does the data you need to convert (1st column) is ALWAYS a vector of 1's with strongly 3 holes of 0's? Does VBA array function is suitable for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using helper columns, first you check location of breaks, and next step get the corresponding times.

[image]

Helper formulas:

```
=MATCH(1,INDIRECT(H1),0)
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H$1),H2,0)="",0),0)+H2
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H$1),H3,0)="",0),0)+H3
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H$1),H4,0)=1,0),0)+H4
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H$1),H5,0)="",0),0)+H5
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(H$1),H6,0)="",0),0)+H6-1
```

Formulas to get time:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,H2)
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,H3)
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,H4)
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,H5)
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,H6)
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,H7)
```

The formula looks also for the end of lunch brake, and supppose tea times to take only one time slot.
If tea breaks are longer than 30 min, or any breaks are missing the formula won't work correctly.